# how to print out something instead of geting an error when list.pop function is out of range?

Tags: python

My training course task is to make a shoppingcart, everything works as intented but I can't figure out the function pop out of range problem.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
class Cart:

    shoppingcart = []

    def addstuff(self):
        esine = input("What will be added?: ")
        self.shoppingcart.append(esine)

    def remove(self):
        esine2 = input("Which item is deleted?: ")
        self.shoppingcart.pop(int(esine2))

def main():
    customer = Cart()
    while True:
        selection = input("Would you like to \n"
                          "(1)Add or \n"
                          "(2)Remove items or \n"
                          "(3)Quit: ")

        if selection == "1":
            customer.addstuff()

        if selection == "2":
            print("There are", len(customer.shoppingcart), "items in the list.")
            customer.remove()

        if selection == "3":
            print("The following items remain in the list:")
            for i in \
                    customer.shoppingcart:
                print(i)

            break

        if selection > "3":
            print("Incorrect selection.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Problem is while deleting(poping) an item that is out of range it gives an error but instead should print out "incorrect selection."
I tried adding if True and else argument into def remove part but that doesn't help.

Comment: Use a try/except block. :-) `try:` `self.shoppingcart.pop(int(esine2))` `except:` `print("incorrect selection.")`

Comment: ``if esine2 >= len(self.shoppingcart):`` ...

Comment: Note that there is only a *single* ``shoppingcart = []`` shared by all ``Cart`` instances. Instead of defining it at *class* scope, define it in ``__init__`` instead.

Comment: Any reason for using `pop` here? Why not `list.remove()`?

Comment: @DevangSanghani, why not `del list[index]`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght because the input is the item itself and not the index.

Comment: @DevangSanghani, who says? code uses index

Comment: Assumption that the intention here is to delete an item based on the verbiage of the input question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try` `except` blocks.

```py
emptylist = []
try:
    emptylist.pop()
except IndexError:
    print('pop failed')
```

In your code:

```py
def remove(self):
    esine2 = input("Which item is deleted?: ")
    try:
        self.shoppingcart.pop(int(esine2))
    except IndexError:
        print('no item at index {}'.format(int(esine2))
```

Do note that `pop(i)` removes the item in the list at place `i`, not the item with value `i`.

Comment: `del some_list[index]`?

Comment: `del` is indeed a viable (and probably an even more pythonic way) since `pop` is especially aimed at also processing the item that you popped from the list. However, since OP specifically asked for `pop`, I stayed with it